# Downloading youtube video using swift issue

Tags: ios, swift, download, youtube, alamofire

Iam trying to download a video link on youtube.
I got the download link, but when it is downloaded, the file has no extension(Attached is the image[image: Video saved name])

I used alamofire to download the video

```
    var destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)


         destination = { (tempURL:URL,resp:HTTPURLResponse) in
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,
                                                                    .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let documentsURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath, isDirectory: true)
            var fileURL:URL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(resp.suggestedFilename!)

            return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }
self.request=Alamofire.download((url.absoluteString), to: destination)
        .downloadProgress { progress in
            print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            self.progressView.setProgress(value: CGFloat(progress.fractionCompleted)*100, animationDuration: 0)
        }
        .responseData { response in


            self.request=nil

            if response.result.value != nil {

                self.videoDetails["date"]=String(describing: NSDate())
                self.videoDetails["videoPath"]=response.destinationURL?.path
                self.progressView.setProgress(value: 0, animationDuration: 0)
                }
}
```

How could I dowbload the file with its real extension.
I tried to add an extension like mp4 for it but I couldnt play the video

Comment: thats because youtube dont allow direct download from a url

Comment: I got the download link ... I have problem with downloading it and saving it with its real extension. It is downloaded as "video"  not video.mp4

Comment: can you make sure that if you paste the link in browser it starts downloading the video?